# TypeScript Highlighting in Coda on MacOS

Tags: macos, typescript, coda

I am trying to get my Coda editor to highlight TypeScript properly. This page says that TypeScript is supported

https://library.panic.com/coda-ios/cios-syntax-modes/

However, in my Coda (which is up-to-date), the list of supported languages differs somewhat. How can I get TypeScript to highlight properly?

Comment: this have support for IOS ( IPAD ) not OSX ( MacBook )

Answer (score 10):

You can add code highlighting in the Preferences under the "Editor" tab. Towards the bottom there's a section for "Custom Syntax Modes". Adding .ts as JavaScript will highlight TypeScript mostly right.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with QuickLook to enable Coda 2 to create previews for .ts files. Please add that Panic!

Comment: Thanks. And, yes, I wish this editor would support more highlights and auto-suggests! It is by far my favorite IDE.